# Is there an analytic function $f$ on $B(0,1)$ the open ball with radius 1 such that $f(1/n)=e^{-n}$ for $n=2,3,4,...$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there an analytic function $f$ on $B(0,1)\subset\mathbb{C}$ such that $f(1/n)=e^{-n}$ for $n=2,3,4,...$? I know the following doesn't work:

Let $g(z)=\exp(-1/z)$. Then, $f=g$ on a sequence with a limit point in $B(0,1)$ and so $f=g$ on $B(0,1)$. Since $g$ is not $\mathbb{C}$-differentiable at $0$, neither is $f$ and so such a function cannot exist.

This is not the solution because you cannot use the identity principle with a non analytic function like $\exp(-1/z)$ is not analytic at $z=0$. Any help using the identity principle another way?

Comment: Almost identical: [If $f$ is analytic and $|f(1/n)| < e^{-n}$ for all $n > 0$, why is $f(z) = 0$ for all $z$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287448/if-f-is-analytic-and-f1-n-e-n-for-all-n-0-why-is-fz-0-fo).

Comment: Thank you Martin! I didn't find that in my searches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's another way to do it. Assume that such an $f$ exists. Then we can write
$$ f(z) = z^k g(z) $$
for some (positive due to the assumptions) integer $k$ and some holomorphic function $g$ on $B(0,1)$ with $g(0) \neq 0$. Plug in $z=1/n$:
$$
e^{-n} = f(1/n) = \frac{1}{n^k} g(1/n)
$$
i.e.
$$
g(1/n) = n^k e^{-n}.
$$
Let $n \to \infty$. This gives (by continuity of $g$) that $g(0)=0$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Why can we represent $f$ this way?

Comment: Is it because $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is analytic so it has taylor series in a neighborhood of 0 $f=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nz^n=z^kg(z)$?

Comment: @TonyS.F. Yes, that's right.